# How do I convert a timetable dataframe to a long format?

Tags: r

Intro: This is a question that I wanted to ask, but ended up solving myself. I hope that the answer might still be of use to someone, so I'm leaving it here as an answered question.

---

I have a timetable dataset for trains. I want to convert it to a long format.

This is what my data looks like:

```
  Train    AMS-A     AMS-D      UTR-A     UTR-D  
 ------- --------- --------- ----------- ------- 
  1       03:00     03:10     06:40       07:00  
  2       04:00     04:10     07:40       08:00
```

So I have two columns per station, one for the arrival time and one for the departure time.

This is the format I want to convert it to:

```
  Train   Station   Arrival   Departure  
 ------- --------- --------- ----------- 
      1   AMS       03:00     03:10      
      1   UTR       06:40     07:00      
      2   AMS       04:00     04:10      
      2   UTR       07:40     08:00
```

The part I struggle with, is that the column names contain both a variable that I want as separate columns (arrival / departure) and a variable that I want as separate row values (station).

Some data:

```
d <- structure(list(train = c(1, 2, 1),
                    NYC.A = structure(seq(0.1,0.3,0.1), format = "h:m:s", class = "times"),
                    NYC.D = structure(seq(0.1,0.3,0.1) + .01, format = "h:m:s", class = "times"),
                    BOS.A = structure(seq(0.1,0.3,0.1) + .1, format = "h:m:s", class = "times"),
                    BOS.D = structure(seq(0.1,0.3,0.1) + .11, format = "h:m:s", class = "times")),
               class = "data.frame", .Names = c("train", "NYC.A", "NYC.D", "BOS.A", "BOS.D"), row.names = 1:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem in the following way:

```
f <- tidyr::gather(d, train) %>%
  setNames(c('train', 'event', 'time')) %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = 2, into = c("station", "arr.dep"), sep = "[.]") %>%
  reshape2::dcast(formula = train + station ~ arr.dep, value.var = 'time') %>%
  dplyr::mutate(train = factor(train)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) structure(x, format = 'h:m:s', class = 'times'))
```

This consists of the following steps:

1. Convert into long format using `gather`.
2. Change the column names (because `gather` makes them really weird for some reason)
3. Split the combined column into two using `separate`. The `sep` argument is a regular expression, so wrap the `.` with square brackets to make it literal.
4. Using `dcast`, turn the `arr.dep` variable back into two columns of time data.
5. This last step screwed up your time data type, so convert the numerics back to times.

There is one last catch: the `dcast` method means that every combination of `train` and `station` must occur only ONCE. If the data contains more rows for one train, `dcast` will start returning counts and you don't want that. There is also a simple solution: before you begin, create a unique identifier for every row in the data, which guarantees that there will be one `A` and one `D` row per ID in the data. You can then use `dcast` based on this unique identifier.